# scope in directive breaks view scope with async validation

Tags: angularjs

I am following a Year of Moo tutorial on async form validations and ngMessages (I'm using 1.3.0-beta.14 so I can't use the actual `$async` validator).

My validation is working, but the scope in the view is non-existent! On form submission, there is no `username` value and adding the appropriate `{{username}}` binding elsewhere in the view never returns a value. However, the console Log at the end of my directive does return the correct value, it just never transfers to the view?

Here is the directive, basically lifted from the article (the `console.log` before the final `return` does log the correct value from the view):

```
.directive('recordAvailabilityValidator', function($http) {

  return {
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      var apiUrl = attrs.recordAvailabilityValidator;

      function setAsLoading(bool) {
        ngModel.$setValidity('recordLoading', !bool);
      }

      function setAsAvailable(bool) {
        ngModel.$setValidity('recordAvailable', bool);
      }

      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        if(!value || value.length == 0) return;

        setAsLoading(true);
        setAsAvailable(false);

        $http.get(apiUrl, { params: {attr : value }} )
          .success(function(response) {
            setAsLoading(false);
            setAsAvailable(true);
          })
          .error(function() {
            setAsLoading(false);
            setAsAvailable(false);
          });

        console.log(value)
        return value;
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the relevant part of the html template:

```
  <p>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="signup.username" class='form-control' name='username'
           require minlength='3' record-availability-validator="/api/v1/validations/username"
           ng-model-options="{ debounce : { 'default' : 500, blur : 0 } }">
  </p>
  <div ng-messages="signupForm.username.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a username</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Username must be at least 4 characters</div>
    <div ng-message="recordLoading">Checking database...</div>
    <div ng-message="recordAvailable">The username is already in use...</div>
  </div>
  {{signup.username}}
```

The debug `{{signup.username}}` never shows a value. If I change it to just `{{signup}}` the other values show fine. Also, if I add this directive to another input, like `email` the same strange behavior is there. I googled around and tried added `scope: true` to my directive, but nothing happened.

Comment: When using `minlength` the ng-model value will be `undefined` if it fails validation. Might that be causing problems? If you comment out the entire `$http` call does the problem still persist?

Comment: Nope, good thinking though. I was able to fix this by just pushing angular up to 1.3.0-rc.2, must've just been a bug or something

Comment: Glad you fixed it, though that's a relatively unsatisfying way of fixing a bug.